# How to authenticated in Servicestack Web API and get access to [Authenticate] filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, servicestack

Let's say i'm already send the **custom** authentication data from my client and retrieve the ss-id from the service stack Web API.

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://somewhere/API");
var response = client.Post(new Auth() {UserName = "myuser", Password = "password123"});
```

and then I try to access another API function with [Authenticate], but it always fail with 401 not authorize.

```
public class UsersServices : Service
{
    public UsersRepository Repository { get; set; }

    //cannot access this...
    [Authenticate]
    public object Get(Users user)
    {
        return RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(
            base.Cache, UrnId.Create<Users>("requestAll"), () =>
            {
                var data = Repository.GetAllUsers();
                return data;
            });
    }
}
```

How I can access the API on the client side after the authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SetCredentials` to pass auth info with each client request.

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://somewhere/API");
client.SetCredentials("myuser","password123");
var response = client.Get<ResponseDTO>();
```

Comment: Hi, do I need authenticated first like above, or just straight forward using SetCredential function?

Comment: Just `SetCredential` on each new instance of your service client.

Comment: Hi, it didn't work...i tried like this: client.Get<someDTO>("http://somewhere/API/Users");